# dynamic backbone query with query-engine

Tags: javascript, json, object, backbone.js, query-engine

i just started using https://github.com/bevry/query-engine

i would like to know how i could create querys with dynamic data inside.

here a code example:

```
var query = "Berlin";
queryObject = '{"City":{$contains: "'+query+'"}}';
queryCollection.query(queryObject);

//TypeError: Object.keys called on non-object

queryObject = {"City":{$contains: "Berlin"}} ; 
queryCollectionquery.(queryObject);
//working as expected
```

Any Ideas?

[dfsq is right](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15575089/1111960)

Edit: can this be extended to the object property:

```
query = 'Berlin', 
filter = 'City', 
queryObject = {filter: {$contains: query}};
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well `queryobject` has to be an object, not string. Try this:

```
var query = "Berlin",
queryObject = {City: {$contains: query}};
```

*Note: quotes around object keys usually are not necessary*.

Comment: of course this is correct. is it possible to make do the same with the property like this:

query = 'Berlin', 
filter = 'City',
queryObject = {filter: {$contains: query}};

Answer (score 0):

I think this is what you are looking for. Since you would like to set the key with a variable you need to use bracket notation; if you use dot notation the filter will be set to 'filter' and not the string stored in the variable.

```
var filter = 'City';
var query  = 'Berlin';

var queryObject = {};
queryObject[filter] = {$contains: query};
```